# Trying to exit "recovery mode"

Tags: iphone

I've inadvertently put my iPhone 4 in "recovery mode" and now it insists I restore without even a chance to backup. Is there a way to exit recovery mode?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with [TinyUmbrella](http://thefirmwareumbrella.blogspot.co.at). Launch TinyUmbrella, connect your iPhone and give it some time until it's recognized by TinyUmbrella. Then click the “Exit Recovery” button.

Answer (score 0):

If your iPhone is stuck in Recovery mode, you can easily get it back to normal operation with just a single click.

[Download Reiboot](http://teamcydia.com/download-reiboot-easily-enter-and-exit-recovery-mode-on-iphone-without-itunes/) and install it. Then follow the steps below:

1. Launch Reiboot on your Windows PC or Mac.
2. Connect your iPhone in question to your computer. Reiboot will automatically recognize it.
3. Click on "Exit Recovery Mode" button. That is it.

I hope that helps. Credits: [Team Cydia](http://teamcydia.com/)